# How reduce badbox sensitivity locally?

Tags: warnings, badness

In my document I have a `Underfull \vbox (badness 2662)`. I want to ingnore this specific badbox but none of the others. Therefore, I want to make LaTeX locally less sensitive to badboxes. I tried

```
\vbadness=3000
<some code>
\vbadness=0
```

where the last command is intended to turn the "ignore badboxes mode" off again. However, I then get a lot of "badness < 100 or somehing like that" messages, which I didn't get before. I suppose `\vbadness=0` is somewhat too little.

What's LaTeX's default mode, I mean, if I don't interfere at all which is the badness threshold under which LaTeX doesn't complain?

Comment: @egreg answered the question as asked but it is hard to think of a situation where you know which box it is but you can not make it less bad: you just have to add some stretchable vertical space to the box, it may not make a visible difference as TeX is stretching anyway but complaining about it, if you add some glue it won't complain.

Comment: That sounds interesting and is possibly a better solution than to interfere with TeX's badness assessment. Could you possibly give an example of how your solution would work? The point is I am not even sure what "my box" is!? I just suspect that the problem occurs within a certain `align` environment ... maybe I should go more into the details: I have an align environment with 3 lines. As usual I set `\allowdisplaybreaks` to the hightes value, i.e. 4. The environment is at the end of a page. Without my interfering I get an overfull `\vbox` which looks really bad.  ... cont'd in next comment!

Comment: Continued from previous comment: ... Therefore, I forbid a pagebreak after the 2nd line by using `\\*`. As a result, the page is broken after the first line and I get an underfull `\vbox`, probably in this first line ... but I am not quite sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should revert to the previous value; either reset the parameter in a group, or do

```
\edef\prevvbadness{\the\vbadness}\vbadness=3000
<code>
\vbadness=\prevvbadness\relax
```

The default value of `\vbadness` in LaTeX is 1000, but with the code above you don't need to know.

Usually the route

```
\begingroup\vbadness=3000
<code>
\endgroup
```

is preferable, but I understand that in some cases one can prefer not to enter a group.

Comment: What could be a disadvantage of putting it into a group?

Comment: the group scope affects the macro layer so it isn't always easy to add a group just around the box in a way that doesn't change the definitions seen by following code. On the other hand almost all vertical boxes in latex are made by variants of `\parbox` in which case there is already a local group you can use.